# No type or protocol named 'FlutterPlugin'

Tags: ios, flutter, nsobject

When I try to flutter build ios or just run on iOS simulator, it fails with following error:

Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
In file included from
/Users/hh/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.7+3/ios/Classes/FLTShare
dPreferencesPlugin.m:5:
/Users/hh/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.7+3/ios/Classes/FLTShare
dPreferencesPlugin.h:7:51: error: no type or protocol named 'FlutterPlugin'
@interface FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin : NSObject
^
/Users/hh/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.7+3/ios/Classes/FLTShare
dPreferencesPlugin.m:11:41: error: no type or protocol named 'FlutterPluginRegistrar'

- (void)registerWithRegistrar:(NSObject *)registrar {
  ^
  /Users/hh/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.7+3/ios/Classes/FLTShare
  dPreferencesPlugin.m:12:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FlutterMethodChannel'
  FlutterMethodChannel *channel = [FlutterMethodChannel methodChannelWithName:CHANNEL_NAME
  ^
  /Users/hh/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.7+3/ios/Classes/FLTShare
  dPreferencesPlugin.m:12:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'channel'
  FlutterMethodChannel *channel = [FlutterMethodChannel methodChannelWithName:CHANNEL_NAME
  ^
  /Users/hh/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.7+3/ios/Classes/FLTShare
  dPreferencesPlugin.m:12:36: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FlutterMethodChannel'
  FlutterMethodChannel *channel = [FlutterMethodChannel methodChannelWithName:CHANNEL_NAME
  ^
  /Users/hh/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.7+3/ios/Classes/FLTShare
  dPreferencesPlugin.m:14:4: error: use of undeclared identifier 'channel'
  [channel setMethodCallHandler:^(FlutterMethodCall *call, FlutterResult result) {
  ^
  6 errors generated.
  note: Using new build system
  note: Building targets in parallel
  note: Planning build
  note: Constructing build description

Encountered error while building for device.

And this is how it looks in xcode

[xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KilkJ.jpg)

Flutter Doctor output:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale en-IN)
• Flutter version 1.17.5 at /Users/hh/Developer/flutter
• Framework revision 8af6b2f (3 weeks ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
• Engine revision ee76268252
• Dart version 2.8.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
• Android SDK at /Users/hh/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 11.4.1, Build version 11E503a
• CocoaPods version 1.9.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin version 43.0.1
• Dart plugin version 191.8593
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
• iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) • 7983738B-844D-4B69-98BF-D93F5F3550AB • ios •
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-4 (simulator)

• No issues found!

Please help